# Heroku error code H10n cant run app

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm using flask and python (2.7).  I built an app that run no problem on localhost, but now it will not run on heroku.

the error that im getting when i run heroku log --tail is:
with running heroku restart:

```
    17-05-25T17:22:27.879428+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python project.py`
    2017-05-25T17:22:32.083014+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    2017-05-25T17:22:32.086435+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with stat
    2017-05-25T17:22:32.410829+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!
    2017-05-25T17:22:32.425538+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: 308-659-015
    2017-05-25T17:23:23.016962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
    2017-05-25T17:23:23.879234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2017-05-25T17:23:24.135864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2017-05-25T17:23:26.983758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python project.py`
    2017-05-25T17:23:31.588440+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    2017-05-25T17:23:31.591852+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with stat
    2017-05-25T17:23:32.223153+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!
    2017-05-25T17:23:32.247252+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: 211-683-280
    2017-05-25T17:23:57.249472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=park-picker.herokuapp.com request_id=061f52b3-38e4-4126-b6e3-90129eff15a8 fwd="73.240.112.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-25T17:22:27.879428+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python project.py`
2017-05-25T17:22:32.083014+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2017-05-25T17:22:32.086435+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with stat
2017-05-25T17:22:32.410829+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!
2017-05-25T17:22:32.425538+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: 308-659-015
2017-05-25T17:23:23.016962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-05-25T17:23:23.879234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-05-25T17:23:24.135864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-05-25T17:23:26.983758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python project.py`
2017-05-25T17:23:31.588440+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2017-05-25T17:23:31.591852+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Restarting with stat
2017-05-25T17:23:32.223153+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger is active!
2017-05-25T17:23:32.247252+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debugger PIN: 211-683-280
2017-05-25T17:23:57.249472+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=park-picker.herokuapp.com request_id=061f52b3-38e4-4126-b6e3-90129eff15a8 fwd="73.240.112.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-25T17:24:27.034926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2017-05-25T17:24:27.034926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2017-05-25T17:24:27.206980+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-25T17:24:27.186502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2017-05-25T17:24:28.221792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=park-picker.herokuapp.com request_id=cac9dc85-6e54-4bbe-b0a1-91f0a4fd5531 fwd="73.240.112.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-25T17:24:29.063671+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=park-picker.herokuapp.com request_id=04215139-8e22-4d61-9e28-8fddab312da4 fwd="73.240.112.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-25T17:24:29.750162+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=park-picker.herokuapp.com request_id=6db46984-3a90-4dc8-af96-b0bbf97e1f4c fwd="73.240.112.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have tried most everything I can find, I even changed my app.run() to empty instead of `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507)))` in an attempt to allow for heroku to define that itself (which I believe caused the H20 error, this has been changed back).

my proc file is:

```
web: python project.py
```

and my requirements.txt was generated by
 `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

The project was originally built using a VM, so I even tried removing the Vagrantfile, to no effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm at a loss, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `project.py` I was missing the `import os` statement

Issue resolved.